# PHP:\n not effective in file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to write som text I make in JavaScript to a file server-side and everything works fine on that part, but when I try to make line breaks nothing happens. "\n" and "\r\n" is removed from the string (indicating that it's understood) but text shows as single line.
It's been so long since I dabbled in PHP and JS so all my code is mix and match.

My JS code (located in a separate .js file):

```
function writeData(){
    var rows = document.getElementById("dataTable").rows;
    var text = "";

    for (var r = 0; r < rows.length; r++){
        var tempText = '"' + rows[r].cells[0].innerHTML + '";"' + rows[r].cells[1].innerHTML + '";"' + rows[r].cells[2].innerHTML + '";"' + rows[r].cells[3].innerHTML + "\"\r\n";
        if (!checkEmpty(tempText))text += tempText;
    }

    document.getElementById('tempText').value = text;
    document.getElementById('saveBtn').click();
}
```

My PHP code (located in the index.php):

```
<?php
    $file = 'data2.csv';
    $fileWrite = '';
    if(isset($_POST['fileWrite']) && !empty($_POST['fileWrite'])) {
        $fileWrite = $_POST['fileWrite'].PHP_EOL;   
    }

    file_put_contents($file, $fileWrite);
?>
```

What it currently does is as follows:
It gets all data from the dataTable, makes a string formatted in csv style, adds the formatted text to a hidden textbox (contained in a form) in the index page presses an invisible submit button that runs the PHP code.

I've tried all answers I could find that I understood but I still get an output like this:

```
"Some";"Thing";"Is";"Wrong""This";"Is";"not";"Working"
```

But should look like this:

```
"Some";"Thing";"Is";"Wrong"
"This";"Is";"not";"Working"
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing \r\n by the constant PHP_EOL : http://php.net/manual/fr/reserved.constants.php

Comment: I think it might be an encoding issue of the EOL? Try to use `encodeURIComponent()` in JS and then `url_decode()` in PHP. I'm not sure because your code is incomplete. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The 'encodeURIComponent()' and 'url_decode()' worked even when I remove '\\r\\n'. Thank you

Comment: How are you verifying that the file does not have the line breaks? Have you tried a simple `cat data2.csv`?

Comment: I opened the file in Notepad++ an set it to show All Characters.